# Brew install groovy fails

Tags: macos, groovy, homebrew, adoptopenjdk

When I try to run `brew install groovy` it tells me

```
groovy: Java 1.7+ is required to install this formula.
Install AdoptOpenJDK with Homebrew Cask:
  brew cask install adoptopenjdk
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

I ran `brew cask install adoptopenjdk` like it says, but when I run `brew install groovy` again, I get a popup that says

```
“adoptopenjdk-13.0.2.jdk” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
```

[Screenshot of the popup, stackoverflow won't let me embed images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIAJB.png)

Anyone seen this before or know what to do?

Comment: I always have more success with https://sdkman.io/

Answer (score 2):

Go to "System Preferences", "Security & Privacy".  In the "General" tab you hopefully will see an option to "Allow Anyway" for adoptopenjdk.  The next time you run it there will still be a popup but this time you can "open" the program.  Then... after that... no more pop ups.